# How to hide task delay output in powershell?

Tags: .net, multithreading, powershell

I'm trying to use the task delay .NET function in a PoSh script, but I am finding odd behavior when I try to keep it quiet.

`[system.threading.tasks.task]::Delay(1000*$seconds)`

waits `$seconds` seconds and gives output like:

```
Result                 : System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult
Id                     : 99
Exception              :
Status                 : RanToCompletion
IsCanceled             : False
IsCompleted            : True
CreationOptions        : None
AsyncState             :
IsFaulted              : False
AsyncWaitHandle        : System.Threading.ManualResetEvent
CompletedSynchronously : False
```

I don't want that output, but any of these

```
$null = [system.threading.tasks.task]::Delay(1000*$seconds)
[system.threading.tasks.task]::Delay(1000*$seconds) |out-null
[void]([system.threading.tasks.task]::Delay(1000*$seconds))
```

return immediately unless `$seconds` is large whereupon there is a minimal delay.  Why would that be and how to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: make PowerShell format it before you drop it... `[system.threading.tasks.task]::Delay(1000*$seconds) |format-table|out-null`

Comment: As an aside: _not_ discarding the output also doesn't wait, because the return value is an asynchronous task object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *immediate* fix is to call [`.Wait()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait) to await the completion of the inherently *asynchronous* task returned by [`[System.Threading.Tasks.Task]::Delay()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay); since `.Wait()` has return type `void`, it outputs nothing, so you don't need output suppression:

```bash
[System.Threading.Tasks.Task]::Delay(1000 * $seconds).Wait()
```

However, a *simpler and more efficient* way to wait *synchronously* is to call [`[System.Threading.Thread]::Sleep()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Threading.Thread.Sleep):

```bash
[System.Threading.Thread]::Sleep(1000 * $seconds)
```

Or, using PowerShell's [`Start-Sleep`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/start-sleep) cmdlet:

```bash
Start-Sleep -Seconds $seconds
```